# Android change activity icon set in Manifest

Tags: android, android-activity, icons, manifest

Here is my manifest :

```
    <activity android:name=".plug.imp.NewActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SYNC" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:icon="@drawable/label_icon">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Here I have set the drawable icon.

Is there a way to set it in the activity itself and remove it from the Manifest?

Thank You.

Comment: Are you talking about the icon used by the Launcher or the ActionBar?

Answer (score 0):

try something like:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.....
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

    //setContentView(R.layout.main);

getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);
 ....

}
```

window_title.xml

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/header" 
    android:src="@drawable/ico_title"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </ImageView>

 </LinearLayout>
```

this is icon of activity title not application icon.